# PHP Webpage not loading - Nothing in apache access logs

Tags: php, apache

I have been seeing a strange problem with one of my PHP page intermittently.

I found that the Page was loading forever and tried to do some tests with curl.

here are the results

1st run- % -> 0 and keptloading until 01:01(I ctrl+c'd)

2nd run responded normally 4 secs load time

3rd run again started to load for more than 5 secs, so ctrl+c'd

4th run responded normally 4 secs load time

[image]

I was tailing the apache access log while i was requesting the pages.
When the page was not loading(aka 0% ) i was not able to see any entries in apache access logs.

for 4 requests i can only see 2 access entries in the apache access log.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2012:17:33:28 -0700] "GET /lmo/auth/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1317 "-" "curl/7.21.7 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5"
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2012:17:33:50 -0700] "GET /lmo/auth/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1317 "-" "curl/7.21.7 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5"
```

- Nothing in the apache error.log either

**More info:**
 1 .The same is the case over HTTP vs HTTPS

2 .i am using win 2003 with xampp 1.8.0(recently updated xampp , and was seeing slower load times  even before i updated.)

3 .apache 2.4 , php 5.4 The page i am loading   has minimal php code, with most of the code being HTML/JS.Its a login   page.

I think that there is some thing wrong going with apache. Can anyone help me on how i could debug this problem?

Comment: Does apache respond normally to static HTML requests? (non php)

Comment: yeah.. i was just printing plain html and looks good, i am guessing, somethings wrong with the included php scripts, the thing i dont understand is that, it suddenly started to behave like this.

Answer (score 0):

What has the PHP script to do for sending you a complete page?
Maybe there is some IOWAIT issue.
Or another deadlock or wait situation which could be filebased. (fopen for example)
or a MySQL transaction which is blocked by another one.

Comment: Good thought, but If that was the case, I'd expect apache logs to acknowledge the initial request before handing it off to php.

Comment: I'm pretty sure apache logs the request after it recieved the output from the php script.

Comment: Otherwise the 'size' of the delivered content could not be in the logfile entry :)

Comment: the size was 0, if you see the curl results screen shot. just removed the php script and the includes int he file and the page loads fine consistently. So i think i need to debug the php included. However it really stumps me how the exact same scripts stopped working suddenly.

Comment: Also this is a test machine that we use , and one of my team mates was testing out his .net web application, and he said that he had to run a Baground process for .net. I am no master in .net, but memory wise, would that cause a problem? Again the same PHP code was working fine since 8 months until this week.

Comment: could you paste the code? or is it too complex or is it top secret?

Comment: does the script continue to run by design after it delivered it's page content? or should it exit after the html closing tag?

Comment: for the moment I'm a bit clueless. Could be anything. But for now I would bet on some weird IO lockup.

Comment: just to ask the obvious... was any used component updated? for example apache/php or used php libraries, openssl, etc.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Unfortunately i cannot paste the code but i can explain what the code does. however I will try to triage the code myself. There are 2 components, 1. utils class i am using which i wrote for common tasks like string manupulation/db tasks/ldap tasks. 2. code to post username and password to self and authenticate against LDAP server, if authenticated, sets session, if not - destroys session.